# Issue with array dimensions during concatenation in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to preprocess data by scaling numeric data and transform categorical data using one hot encoder.
The function below applies this to train and test data, returning for each dataset concatenation of scaled numeric data and encoded categorical data.
But when executing it I keep having  the following error on line

```
trainX = np.hstack([encoded_train, train_numeric_data])"

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

I do not manage to fix this, would anybody have an idea?
Thanks in advance.
Seb

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder


def process_data(train, test):
    # perform min-max scaling for all numeric features (13 columns)
    numeric = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","k","k","l","m"]        
    cs = MinMaxScaler()
    train_numeric_data = cs.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(train,columns=numeric))
    test_numeric_data = cs.transform(pd.DataFrame(test,columns=numeric))

    # one-hot encode categorical data (11 columns)
    categorylist=["n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x"]
    train_categorical_data = pd.DataFrame(train,columns=categorylist)
    test_categorical_data= pd.DataFrame(test,columns=categorylist)

    encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
    encoder.fit(train_categorical_data)
    encoded_train=encoder.transform(train_categorical_data)
    encoded_test=encoder.transform(test_categorical_data)


    # construct our training and testing data points by concatenating the categorical features with the numeric features
    trainX = np.hstack([encoded_train, train_numeric_data])
    testX = np.hstack([encoded_test,test_numeric_data])

    #return the concatenated training and testing data
    return (trainX, testX)
```

Comment: The problem that `train_numeric_data` has incorrect size --  try `print(train_numeric_data.size)`  -- the array is flattened one-dimensional array. You need to reshape the array. Sorry, have to go now, I hope that's a good starting point.

Comment: thank you for the hint. I have tried the print of size and shape and get: 
train_numeric_data.size= 284063    (which is 21851 rows* 13 columns),
train_categorical_data.size= 240361  (which is 21851 rows* 11 columns),
encoded_train.size= 240361. Then using shape it shows:
train_numeric_data.shape= (21851, 13),
train_categorical_data.shape= (21851, 11),
encoded_train.shape= (21851, 176)  . So i don't see  what i need to reshape i want to hstack (21851,13) with (21851,176) what should be reshaped here?

Comment: Hi again, i have printed some data to better understand the structure  train_numeric_data (21851, 13) is like:
[[0.         1.         0.3 ... 0.9     0.9       0.        ]
 [0.3   0.7   0.7 ... 0.02   0.8       0.        ]
 ...
and encoded_train 21851, 176)  is like: 
  (0, 7) 1.0
  (0, 109) 1.0
  (0, 118) 1.0
  (0, 125) 1.0
  (0, 127) 1.0
  (0, 129) 1.0
  (0, 135) 1.0
  (0, 147) 1.0
  (0, 161) 1.0
  (0, 165) 1.0
  (1, 5) 1.0
  (1, 8) 1.0
  ...
  I get the feeling that it is encoded_train that I should reshape but not sure how to do that? Thanks in advance if you can help

Comment: I am glad that you solved the issue. Sorry for not being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually solved the issue by changing type of `encoded_train` with

```
encoded_train_array = pd.DataFrame(encoded_train.toarray())
```